# Compare and contrast ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION and BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION

Tags: android, android-intent

At first I thought that ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION were meant for intents that are dispatched with startActivity and that BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION for those dispatched with sendBroadcast, but then I saw that for example the intent whose action is ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT is dispatched with sendBroadcast even though the action is an ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION. So will someone please explain? I know this may be an advance question to ask, but there are a lot of android experts here. So thanks for any help.

Comment: Most likely, you're seeing a bug in the platform, for when they added the `@SdkConstant` annotations.

Comment: Thanks for replying @CommonsWare . So are you saying my previous assumption is generally correct: i.e. ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION are for startActivity and BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION are for sendBroadcast? It's not clear from your comment. Thanks.

Comment: That would be my assumption as well. I have not paid much attention to the `@SdkConstant` annotations.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I am paying attention because it's not always obvious how an intent action should be dispatched or used. But you have a whole lot of experience so maybe you don't need to bother. But for people like me who are trying to transition from intermediate to advance, it's hard to know what to do without looking at the source code.

Comment: "But you have a whole lot of experience so maybe you don't need to bother" -- I use a search engine and see if I can find examples of how it is used. While hint-style annotations like `@SdkConstantType` are *usually* correct, running code is a better test of how you use an `Intent` action like these.